# Is Spring Boot reactive ( webflux) monitoring any different from monitoring ordinary Spring Boot MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

Are Spring Boot Reactive ( Webflux) metrics any different from ordinary Spring Boot MVC ?

Does reactive streams programming model bring an extra monitoring metrics collecting duty?

Is there in reactive spring something special what need to be monitored at Webflux project specifically?